# How can I get a value from an inline style attribute and put inside the closest input value? jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, replace

How can I get a value from an inline style attribute, remove the '%', and place it inside the closest (or the next) input value attribute?

```
<div>
    <div>
       <div style="width: 52%;"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_1" value="0">
</div>

<div>
    <div>
       <div style="width: 52%;"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_2" value="0">
</div>
```

I need to get the "**52**" of each `<div style="width: 52%;">` and put it inside the closest input value replacing the "0". How can I do this in jQuery? Thanks

Comment: thanks guys I gotta urgently leave I'll test the solutions and accept an answer asap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div[style]').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().val( parseFloat(this.style.width) );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7GA4n/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/z9FSb/

```
$('div[style]').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).attr('style');
    var nstr = str.substr(str.indexOf(':')+1).slice(0, -2);
    var Val = $(this).parent().next('input').val(nstr);
    alert($('[type="hidden"]').val());
});
```